# How to get the class name from a "type" instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable which is an instance of "type" :

```
my_var = type('hello')
```

`str(my_var)` outputs `"<type 'str'>"`

But how can I get the original object name from `my_var`, ie in this case: `str` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as simple as

```
>>> my_var = type('hello')
>>> my_var.__name__
'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `my_var.__name__` to get name as string.